# How to dynamically create a ModelForm based on James Bennett's article "So you want a dynamic form"?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

In James Bennett's article ["So you want a dynamic form"](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) (Nov. 9, 2008), he wrote that to create a dynamic form you can do something like this:

```
def make_contact_form(user):
    fields = { 'name': forms.CharField(max_length=50),
               'email': forms.EmailField(),
               'message': forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea) }
    if not user.is_authenticated():
        fields['captcha'] = CaptchaField()
    return type('ContactForm', (forms.BaseForm,), { 'base_fields': fields })
```

But how would you do the same thing with `forms.ModelForm`?

So far I'm just doing something like this (I couldn't figure out how to use `type` with an inner class 'Meta')

```
def make_order_edit_form(include_fields):
    class _OrderEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
        if 'fa_date' in include_fields:
            fa_date = CustomDateTimeField(label="first appointment time")

        class Meta:
            model = Order
            fields = include_fields
            widgets = custom_widgets

    return _OrderEditForm
```

where `include_fields` is a tuple of fields I want to show.

However even if I wrote a correct `make_order_edit_form`, how do I use it in `views.py`? Specifically how do I pass both the POST request and the order instance to it? Normally I would do something like

```
order = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)

order_form = OrderEditForm(data=request.POST, instance=order)
```

**Bonus question:**

Why did Bennett create a `ContactForm` out of `forms.BaseForm` instead of `forms.Form`? (I'm assuming that's why the fields are called `base_fields` as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_order_edit_form` returns a `ModelForm` class, thus you could

```
form_cls = make_order_edit_form(fields)
order_form = form_cls(request.POST, instance=order)
```

For the bonus question, check the `Form` code:

```
class Form(BaseForm):
    "A collection of Fields, plus their associated data."
    # This is a separate class from BaseForm in order to abstract the way
    # self.fields is specified. This class (Form) is the one that does the
    # fancy metaclass stuff purely for the semantic sugar -- it allows one
    # to define a form using declarative syntax.
    # BaseForm itself has no way of designating self.fields.
    __metaclass__ = DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass
```

The `Form` has a customized meta class `DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass` which automatically collects form fields written in declarative syntax, if you use `Form` in `type()`, it looks like (take Bennett's example)

```
type('ContactForm', (forms.Form,), {
    'name': forms.CharField(max_length=50),
    'email': forms.EmailField(),
    'message': forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)}
# instead of
type('ContactForm', (forms.BaseForm,), { 'base_fields': fields })
```

*update*

to build up `ModelForm` using `type`, no much different

```
def make_order_edit_form(include_fields):
    d = {}
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = include_fields
        widgets = custom_widgets 
    d = {'Meta':Meta}
    if 'fa_date' in include_fields:
        d['fa_date'] = CustomDateTimeField(label="first appointment time")
    return type('OrderEditForm', (forms.ModelForm,), d)
```

Comment: Thanks you answered a lot of my questions. So it's not possible to use `type` with `ModelForm`? Also what does `cls` stand for anyway (is this some sort of naming convention)?

Comment: @hobbes3 yes, you can surely use `type` to build up `ModelForm`; `cls` is my own convention =p, seems `class` or `klass` or `class_` are more recommended .